# Does Django have a plugin/app that handles "levels" for users? And certain permissions/rankings for each?

Tags: python, django, plugins

I want to promote users to moderators, admins, etc.

What about scoring and game mechanics? What app takes care of that?

What about **moderation**?  When someone changes a title of a post, it needs 3 more moderators to approve it before it takes affect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using django's built in authentication module, you could create specific "Groups" to assign permissions to, and then promote users by re-assigning the groups they belong to.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/

For specific approvals and use cases you will probably need to write your own handling.